# PayPal API - accept a credit card donation from a desktop app

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card

We have a kiosk type of application with an attached credit card reader.

It allows a person to swipe a credit card and select a specific amount of $ to donate.

What are the steps for passing this data to PayPal and conducting an actual donation transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make HTTPS calls from your kiosk app? If so, you should be able to do this with the new REST based APIs fairly simply. Here's the link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

Hope this helps.